# Websocket Server written in Node.JS running on Heroku keeps crashing with status 0 and error H10. Deployment says upgrade required

Tags: node.js, heroku, websocket

I have written code for a web socket server that should populate a website with data. The code is in HTML and Java Script.

I am facing the following error in the logs:

```
2024-02-28T23:34:41.077771+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2024-02-28T23:34:41.100653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-02-28T23:34:41.103507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-02-28T23:34:44.848641+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node server.js`
2024-02-28T23:34:45.480179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2024-02-28T23:34:45.505198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-02-28T23:34:51.746688+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=5261894c-71a1-480f-a28c-9f093143beeb fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:34:52.379212+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=8d54fa39-84ff-4812-8b56-45e10232a219 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:35:04.901820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=2b700bc4-2608-4fbe-a612-409e39e29398 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:35:05.748517+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=b160b268-555b-45a7-bb59-b22521dd1fc2 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:37:39.646346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=e83baf02-8523-4ee8-9058-259fdd00200a fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:37:40.423376+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=34e08322-a539-43a3-a8e7-d81013b642d2 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2024-02-28T23:41:22.644768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-02-28T23:41:26.988187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node server.js`
2024-02-28T23:41:27.782802+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2024-02-28T23:41:27.807030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-02-28T23:42:04.262903+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=5c9d4fe8-4ebd-485e-b92d-833f02da4ff7 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:42:04.589917+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=07058b6d-11c3-427d-8c30-6098710bfd47 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:43:22.907115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2024-02-28T23:43:27.780258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node server.js`
2024-02-28T23:43:28.646097+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2024-02-28T23:43:28.670831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2024-02-28T23:43:30.169596+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=d0babf54-4a9e-4893-af55-c61fc9ec6a1b fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:43:30.480346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=e5386d09-eee3-4648-8cc2-374acfe866a7 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:44:08.191952+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=5fb82ba0-47c7-4ce2-8eee-e7b3f5d29dc0 fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-02-28T23:44:08.489776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=vast-sierra-19489-50b21f63c402.herokuapp.com request_id=7494a7b9-01f2-491b-87ed-7425a523f7da fwd="223.190.83.12" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2024-02-28T23:55:54.889727+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2024-02-28T23:55:54.940052+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2024-02-28T23:55:55.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2024-02-28T23:55:55.803877+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2024-02-28T23:55:55.892721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2024-02-28T23:55:58.357063+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node server.js`
2024-02-28T23:55:59.428384+00:00 app[web.1]: WebSocket server is listening on port 7493
2024-02-28T23:55:59.468637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

When I do heroku open, it's a blank screen with "Update required" on top

Here's my code for reference:

INDEX.HTML

```
 const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 3000;

    const ws = new WebSocket(`ws://0.0.0.0:${PORT}`)

ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
      console.log("Connected!")
```

PACKAGE.JSON

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.97.6",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.15.16",
    "three": "^0.161.0",
    "ws": "^8.16.0"
  }
```

PROCFILE

```
web: node server.js
```

REQUIREMENTS.TXT

```
websockets
```

SERVER.JS

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

 const PORT =  process.env.PORT || 3000;
 
 const server = new WebSocket.Server({port: PORT});

 server.on("listening", () => {
    console.log(`WebSocket server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
 
 server.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("Client connected!");
```

Any help is appreciated! New to Node and Web Socket and doing a project for an internship test, I need to provide a live cloud based implementation of the website they asked me to function.

I have tried alot of fixes online, mainly Procfile spacing, heroku restart in the CLI and setting web-scale to 1 and so on. One odd thing I noticed is that when i do heroku config, nothing shows up. I did not set anything but used variables I found online and in their documentation. I can also confirm that on the Heroku dashboard, node server.js is ticked as requested.